# Parsing JSON in JS and comparing key values

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, file, parsing

I have a JSON data

```
{
"FrontLeft"  : "FALSE",
"FrontRight" : "FALSE",
"RearLeft"   : "FALSE",
"RearRight"  : "TRUE"  }
```

I read this data from a text file using AJAX and parsed .

```
function loadDoc() 
   {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

      var arrLines = xhttp.responseText;
      alert ( arrLines);
      var obj = JSON.parse(arrLines);
     /*
        Need to compare values of each key
      */


    }
  };
```

How can access values of each key ???

Comment: how do you plan to compare those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the values in the object like this,

```
obj.FrontLeft     //this will give you "FALSE"
obj.FrontRight    //this will give you "FALSE"
```

or `obj['FrontLeft']` will also give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop:

```
for (var key in p) {
 if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
 }
}
```

Or you can use Object.keys(), see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var obj = { 'FrontLeft' : '1', 'FrontLeft1' : '2' };
var keys = Object.keys(foo); // ['FrontLeft', 'FrontLeft1']
```

Another way could be possibly for-of but it does not have wide browser support yet [see MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)